# Statistical test for whether a process is a red noise

Tags: time-series, residuals, arma, white-noise

We know that red noise is the same as a ﬁrst-order autoregressive (AR(1)) stationary Gaussian process with a positive correlation at unit lag. Does there exist some formal statistical test for red noise process?

One way I can think of is to firstly fit an AR(1) model to the process, then perform white noise test on the model residuals to see whether the residuals follow a white noise process. If yes, the original process can be viewed as a red noise process...

Welcome any ideas and comments.

Comment: Just interested, where can I read about why red noise is the same as AR(1) stationary Gaussian process with a positive correlation at unit lag?

Comment: @DmitryLaptev Please refer to: H. von Storch and F. W. Zwiers (1999), Statistical Analysis in Climate Research, Cambridge, England: Cambridge University Press.